# Microservices design part in WebApi

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture, microservices, cqrs

Hi I am trying to create a project skeleton uses [CQRS](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) pattern and some external services. Below are the structure of the solution.

- WebApi
- Query Handlers
- Command Handlers
- Repository
- ApiGateways ( here is the interfaces and implementation of microservice calls)

We want to keep controller as thin. So we are using query handlers and command handlers to handle respective operations.

[image]
However, we use a external microservices to get the data we are calling them from Query handlers. 
All the http clinet construction and calls will be abstracted in them.The response will be converted to a view model and pass it back to Query handler.

We name it as a [ApiGateways](https://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html). But it is not composing from multiple services. 
How do we call this part in our solution? Proxy or something? Any good example for thin controllers and microservice architecture

Comment: If I understand you correctly, representing multiple external services in a single service proxy/facade kinda negates the benefit of MS.  You just end up with a monolithic client proxy

Comment: @MickyD the calls are one to one.. we are not aggregating result from multiple service. So we say them like "OrderServiceProxy"? and group them in a project called ExternalServices, instead GatewayApis?

Answer (score 1):

> We name it as `API Gateway`s. But it is not composed from multiple
>   services. How do we call this part in our solution? Proxy or
>   something? Any good example for thin controllers and microservice
>   architecture

**Assumption:**

From the image you attached, I see Command Handler and Query Handler are calling "external/micro-services". I guess by this "external/micro-services" you mean that you are calling another micro-service from your current micro-service Handler(Command and Query). These "external/micro-services" are part of your architecture and deployed on the same cluster and not some external system that just exposes a public `API`?
If this is correct I will try to answer based on this assumption.

`API Gateway` would probably be misleading in this case as the concept of `API Gateway` is something different then what you are trying to do here.

**`API Gateway` per definition:**

Quote from [here](https://dzone.com/articles/building-microservices-using):

> An `API Gateway` is a server that is the single entry point into the
>   system. It is similar to the Facade pattern from object-oriented
>   design. The `API Gateway` encapsulates the internal system architecture
>   and provides an `API` that is tailored to each client. It might have
>   other responsibilities such as authentication, monitoring, load
>   balancing, caching, request shaping and management, and static
>   response handling.

What you actually are trying to do is to call from your Command or Query Handler from one of your micro-service A another micro-service B. This is an internal micro-service communication that should not be done through `API Gateway` as that would be the approach for outside calls. For example, with "outside calls" I mean frontend application `API` or public `API` calls that are trying to call your micro-services. In that case, you would use `API Gateway`s.

A better name for this component would be something like "CrossMicroServiceGateway" or "InterMicroServiceGateway"; if you want to have it as the full `CQRS` way you could have it like a direct call to other Command or Query and then you could use something like "QueryGate" or "CommandGate" or similar.

**Other suggestions:**

> `WebApi`
>
> Query Handlers
>
> Command Handlers
>
> `Repository`
>
> `API Gateway`s ( here is the interfaces and implementation of
>   microservice calls)

This sounds reasonable except for the point of `API Gateway` which I described above. Of course, it is hard for me to tell based on the limited information that I have about your project. To give you a more precise suggestion here I would need to know whether you use `DDD` or not? How do you use `CQRS` and other information?

> However, we use an external microservices to get the data we are
>   calling them from Query handlers. All the `HTTP` client construction and
>   calls will be abstracted in them. The response will be converted to a
>   view model and pass it back to Query handler.

You could extract all this code/logic that handles the cross micro-service communication over `HTTP` or other protocols, handling general responses and similar to some core library and include it into each of your micro-service as a package. In this way, you will reuse the solution for all your micro-service. You can extend that and add all core domain-agnostic things (like data access or repository base classes, wrappers around `HTTP`, unit-test infrastructure setup, and similar) to that or other shared libraries. This way your micro-services will only focus on the part of the Domain it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think CQRS is the right choice to keep the reading and writing operations decoupled.

The integration with third party systems (if it's the case), need some attention. 
Do not call these services directly from your handlers, this could lead to various performance and/or maintainability issues.

You have to keep these integrations very well separated, because them are out of your domain. They may be subject to inefficiencies, changes or a number of problems out of your control.

One solution that I could recommend is a "Middleware" service.

In your application context this can be constituted by another service (always REST for example) that will have the task of 'talk' (only him) with external systems, acting as a single point of integration between your domain and the external environment. This can be realized from scratch or using a commercial/opens-source solution like (just as example) [this](https://www.mulesoft.com/resources/esb/integration-middleware-technology).

This lead to many benefits, same of these:

- A middleware is a unique mockable point during integration test of your application.
- You can change the middleware implementation in the future without touch your handlers.
- Of course, changing 3pty providers won't affect your domain services.
- Middleware is the unique point dedicated to manage 3pty service interruptions.
- Your services remain agnostic compared to the outside world.

Focus on these questions can be useful to design your integration middleware service:

- Which types of 3pty data do they provide? Are they on time? This might help you figure out whether to introduce a cache system into your integration service.
- Can 3pty be subject to frequent interruptions? Then you must ensure that your system must tolerate any disruption of external services. In other words, you must ensure a certain resilience of your services. There are many [techniques](https://dzone.com/articles/libraries-for-microservices-development) to do that.
- Do you really need to interrogate these 3pty services all the time? Maybe a more or less sophisticated cache system could speed up your services a lot.

Finally, it is also very important to understand if the need to have a microservices-oriented system is a real and immediate need.
Due to the fact these architectures are more expensive and complex then the classic ones, it might be reasonable to think about starting by building a monolith system and then moving towards a more segmented solution later. 
Thinking (organizing) your system as many "[bounded context](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html)" does not prevent you from creating a good monolith system and at the same time, it prepares you for a possible switch to microservices-oriented one.

As a summary advice, start by keeping things as separate as possible. Define a [language](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/UbiquitousLanguage.html) to speak about your business model. These lead to you potentially change a lot when needs will come without to much effort during the inevitable evolution of your software. "[Hexagonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_architecture_(software))" architecture is a good starting point to do that for both choises (Microservices vs Monolith).
Recently, Netflix posted a nice [article](https://netflixtechblog.com/ready-for-changes-with-hexagonal-architecture-b315ec967749) about this architecture with a lot of ideas for a fresh start.

Answer (score 0):

I will give my answer from DDD and the clean architecture perspective. Ideally, you application should have following layers.

1. **Api** (ideally very thin layer of Controllers).The controller will create queries and commands and push them on a common channel. (refer [MediatR](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR))
2. **Application** This will be your orchestration layer. It will contain definitions of queries and command and their handlers. For queries, you will directly interact form your infrastructure layer. For commands, you will interact with domain and then save them through repositories in infrastructure.
3. **Domain** Depends upon your business logic and complexity, this layer will contain all your business models.
4. **Infrastructure** It will contain mostly two types of objects **Providers** and **Repositories**. Providers should be used with queries and will return DAO. Repositories should be used where ever domain is involved, ideally commands in CQRS. Repositories should always receive and return only domain objects.

*So after setting the base context about different layers on clean architecture, the answer to your original question is --> **I would create third party interactions in the provider layer. For example, you need to connect with a user microservice, I will create a UserProvider in the provider folder in the infrastructure layer and consume it through a interface**.*